# Find property of sub child usercontrol in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

There is a User Control - ChildUC.ascx with Property "FirstName"

***ChildUC.ascx***

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChildUC.ascx.cs" Inherits="SampleDevExpress14._2.UserControls.ChildUC" %>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClick" Text="Click" OnClick="btnClick_Click"/>
```

***ChildUC.ascx.cs*** -
This got a property **FirstName**

```
public partial class ChildUC : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

This **ChildUC.ascx** user control used in another user control **ParentUC.ascx**-

**ParentUC.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ParentUC.ascx.cs" Inherits="SampleDevExpress14._2.UserControls.ParentUC" %>
<%@ Register src="ChildUC.ascx" tagPrefix="uc1" tagName="ChildUC" %>

<uc1:ChildUC runat="server" ID="ucChildUC"/>
```

The **ParentUC.ascx** used in a **ParentPage.aspx**

**ParentPage.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ParentPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleDevExpress14._2.UserControls.ParentPage" %>
<%@Register src="ParentUC.ascx" tagPrefix="uc1" tagName="ParentUC" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:ParentUC runat="server" ID="ucParentUC"/>    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ParentPage.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl ucChild = (UserControl)ucParentUC.FindControl("ucChildUC");
            TextBox txtNameOfChildUC = (TextBox)ucChild.FindControl("txtName");
            txtNameOfChildUC.Text = "From Parent Page";
        }
```

I am able to find the **textbox** control of **ChildUC.ascx** in **ParentPage.aspx** which i showed above in **Page_Load event**

But how can I find the **FirstName** Property of **ChildUC.ascx** in **ParentPage.aspx** and set a value to it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying using dynamic,

```
    dynamic u = (UserControl)ParentControl.FindControl("childcontrol");
    u.firstname = "fawad";
    Response.Write(u.firstname);
```